# Javascript store for frontend In Joomla 2.5

Tags: javascript, joomla, storage

Anybody know where we store the Javascript for frontend of joomla component.Joomla searches the javascript from the default path like [http://joomla.com/index.php/file.js]
Even i have set the path but can't set before index.php 
I want to know where i will store the javascript after index.php in Joomla 2.5.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Abhinav. Peoploe will more likely answer your questions if you honor them and accept the answer which helped you. To do so, click on the big green checkmark left to the question of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Well to start off with, the javascript file will need to be called from the component itself and you can store the file in any location.

Most people will call the javascript file from the default.php within the views/tmpl folder.

To call it, you can use the following code:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . 'components/com_your_component/assets/javascript.js');
```

Hope this helps